# MYSQL WITH clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
with tempCTE as(
select *,row_number() over(partition by empid) as rowno from employees);
```

I am getting error 1064 SQL syntax error at line 2

How to overcome this?

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to use your CTE, but you do need a valid SQL statement.  A CTE is more or less a fragment of code which gets inserted into a later statement.  So the following is valid:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empid) AS rowno
    FROM employees
)

SELECT *
FROM cte;
```

But note that *any* select after the CTE would make the entire thing valid as a statement.

Comment: Doesn't have to be a *select* either ^^

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something with your CTE:

```
with tempCTE as(
select *,row_number() over(partition by empid) as rowno from employees)
select * from tempCTE;
```